# Google Api geocoding with postal code

Tags: api, geocoding

i'm trying to use the API Google to have latitude and longitude from an address and a postal code.

I tried to use it :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&region=fr&address=MYADDRESS&postal_code=13002
```

But when i see the results, i can see that i've result with different postal code.. why ?

Answer (score 1):

ok i found my error :

`&components=postal_code:13002`, instead of `postal_code=13002`